# Keyboard with Jetpack Compose was broken by Compose beta-01 (ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[*This is related to this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755763/inputmethodservice-with-jetpack-compose-composeview-causes-composed-into-the)

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755763/inputmethodservice-with-jetpack-compose-composeview-causes-composed-into-the) I was able to create a keyboard with Jetpack Compose. **Now after I upgrade the project from `alpha-11` to `alpha-12` the code broke** (and is still broken in `beta-01`) and I get the following error whenever I try to open the keyboard:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@aaf805f[InputMethod]
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:214)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:151)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:199)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:176)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:207)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2052)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7768)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)
```

That's very weird because I have set the `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` [here](https://github.com/THEAccess/compose-keyboard-ime/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/composeime/IMEService.kt#L17) and worked perfectly fine in previous versions of compose until `alpha-12`

The error gives me no idea of what's broken and what I should change. Maybe you can help me.

[Here you can find all code for a reproducible example](https://github.com/THEAccess/compose-keyboard-ime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146\[MyActivity\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382502/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-from-decorview2da7146myactivity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message says:

> ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@aaf805f[InputMethod]

Compose looks for a `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` set on the `DecorView` of your whole `Window`, not the one set on your View itself.

Therefore instead of setting the `ViewTree`s on the `ComposeKeyboardView` you return, instead use the `InputMethodService` API of [`getWindow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#getWindow()) with `getDecorView()` to get the DecorView of your window.

```
override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
    val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)
    window?.window?.decorView?.let { decorView ->
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
        ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(decorView, this)
    }
    return view
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand why it worked before. You've forgot an `window?` in the chain. I suggested an edit

Comment: The changes were deep in how recomposition happens, particularly in cases where you had nested composition scopes (i.e., a `ComposeView` that inflates an `AndroidView` that then inflates a `ComposeView` - nested, but separate scopes) that now requires a global idea of Lifecycle and the Window's `decorView` is that storage mechanism.

Comment: Now animations are broken. Is that related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448080/animations-and-effects-broken-on-keyboard-written-in-jetpack-compos ?

Comment: No idea about that one, sorry.

Comment: ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner now no longer exists

Comment: @thouliha - the APIs certainly still exist (in fact, if your code was in Java it would still look exactly the same), but if you [read the release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/savedstate#1.2.0), you'll see that they are now Kotlin extensions on View.