# Animations and Effects broken on Keyboard written in Jetpack Compose after upgrading to beta-01

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I ran into a problem after **updating my keyboard written completely in Jetpack Compose from Compose version `alpha-11` to `beta-01`.**

Before the upgrade, the UI worked just fine as you would expect. Ripples were displayed fine.
After the upgrade animations and effects (like button pressed) don't play correctly (Ripple effects seem to get *stuck*).
Take a look:

[image: 1]

This is the **desired behavior** and how it looked like before the version upgrade:

[image: 2]

Note: The same code outside of `ComposeKeyboardView` worked perfectly fine. Also, the same code worked perfectly fine before Jetpack Compose `alpha-11` and `beta-01`.
I'm not sure if it is a bug or if I can fix the problem myself.
I appreciate any help or hints to restore the desired behavior.

You can reproduce the problem using the following code:

Keyboard.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Keyboard() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(color = Color.Black, text = "This should resemble a keyboard")
        Button(modifier = Modifier.width(250.dp),onClick = {  }) {
            Text(text = "A Button")
        }
    }
}
```

ComposeKeyboardView.kt

```kotlin
class ComposeKeyboardView constructor(
    context: Context,

    ) : AbstractComposeView(context) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Keyboard()
       
    }
}
```

IMEService.kt

```kotlin
class IMEService : InputMethodService(), LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner,
    SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)
        window!!.window!!.decorView.let { decorView ->
            ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
            ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
            ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(decorView, this)
        }
        return view
    }


    //Lifecycle Methods

    private var lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return lifecycleRegistry
    }


    private fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) =
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        savedStateRegistry.performRestore(null)
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }


    //ViewModelStore Methods
    private val store = ViewModelStore()

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore = store

    //SaveStateRegestry Methods

    private val savedStateRegistry = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    override fun getSavedStateRegistry(): SavedStateRegistry = savedStateRegistry.savedStateRegistry
```

Don't forget to add the IMEService to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<application>
[...]
<service
            android:name=".IMEService"
            android:label="Example Comopose IME"

            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>
</application>
```

app\build.gradle

```
[...]
dependencies {
    def compose_version = "1.0.0-beta01"  
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
}
```

*Edit:* Same problem in compose-beta02

[Or you can find all code here and clone it directly](https://github.com/THEAccess/compose-keyboard-ime)

Comment: Sorry, but we need posts to _stand on their own_, with your [mre] **here, inside the question**. External sites cannot be guaranteed to exist as long as questions on Stack Overflow may last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your code and saw [your comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182024841) in the Compose's bug tracker.
Looks like that if you do the following in your `IMEService` class, the animation works.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    savedStateRegistry.performRestore(null)
    handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) // << here
}
```

[image]