# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-overlay

When I try to insert Compose in overlay(draw over other apps) with XML I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{d596746 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
```

But without overlay(in activity) it works normal. Does anyone know how to resolve? I already updated AppCompat library to 1.3.0

My XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Overlay code:

```kotlin
mParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.power_overlay, null)
mParams!!.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
mWindowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65755763/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66447195/115145 for an example of using Compose outside of a activity or fragment (in that case, an IME).

Comment: I think you mean ConstraintLayout in the first line, instead of Compose; consider removing the Android-jetpack-compose tag, please

Comment: Update androidx.appcompat:appcompat to latest version 1.3.0

Comment: @MuthuramanSundararaj already did this.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: means your trying to do something when its not ready, thats why it works when you remove it, you need to find out the appropriate moment to do this. can you try in onResume ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146\[MyActivity\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382502/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-from-decorview2da7146myactivity)

Answer (score 8):

For me it was because I had not included the *appcompat* library and my activity inherited from *Activity* instead of *AppCompatActivity*. The problem resolved by adding the library:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
```

and inheriting from *AppCompatActivity*:

```kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, upgrade `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` from `1.0.0` to `1.4.1`, the problem solved.

The fragment:

```
class Xxx : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xxx, container, false)

    view.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(
            ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
        )
        setContent {
            // compose
        }
    }
    return view
}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working with drawing overlay from foregound service and for me problem was  here:

```
contentView = ComposeView(this).apply {
    setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this@ForegroundService)
    setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(this@ForegroundService) // <-- missing line.
    setContent {
        OverlayComposeUi()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your constraint layout is updated to latest version in app level `build.gradle` file.

---

```
dependencies { ...    
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.3.x'
```

2. To be sure, search & Replace **ALL** your xml tag names

---

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>

 //with ->

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in every place <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> + <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd>
_

3. And inside `gradle.properties` **add** these:

---

```
 android.enableJetifier=true
 android.useAndroidX=true
```

4. Clear out/**Invalidate Caches** and Restart Android Studio.

---

> **File** → **Invalidate Caches / Restart** → **Invalidate and Restart**

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code and it works.

```
class AndroidComposeDialog<T>(
    private val activity: T,
    private val content: @Composable () -> Unit
) : Dialog(activity) where T : Context, T : androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, T : ViewModelStoreOwner, T : SavedStateRegistryOwner, T : OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner {


    private fun initViewTreeOwners() {
        val window = window ?: return
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(window.decorView, activity)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(window.decorView, activity)
        window.decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(activity)
        window.decorView.setViewTreeOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner(activity)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //here i init view tree owner that will be used by compose view
        initViewTreeOwners()
        //here i hide background of dialog
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT))
        val view = ComposeView(context).apply {
            setContent(content)
        }
        setContentView(view)
    }
}


// A function that returns an android dialog based on entered content
@Composable
fun androidDialog(content: @Composable () -> Unit): AndroidComposeDialog<*>? {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val activity = context as? AppCompatActivity
    val componentActivity = context as? ComponentActivity
    val dialog = remember(activity, content.hashCode()) {
        if (activity != null)
            AndroidComposeDialog(activity = activity, content = content)
        else if (componentActivity != null)
            AndroidComposeDialog(activity = componentActivity, content = content)
        else null
    }
    return dialog
}
```

and now it's ready to use

```
@Composable
fun ShowDialog() {
    val dialog = androidDialog {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = {
            dialog?.show()
        }, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
            Text(text = "show dialog")
        }
    }
}
```